# Change the content of the grid row

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I apologize if the question is easily answerable, but I am new to WPF.

I have a grid with 2 rows. First row will contain menu, and the second row has its content set in response to the menu item click.

For simplicity, let us take I have 2 menu items and 2 user controls.

Here is the example scenario:

At the beginning of the program, only menu is shown and the second grid row is empty.

User chooses first menu item -> second grid row should now contain first user control.

Now user chooses second menu item, so second row should contain second user control (while the previous content is deleted).

### QUESTION:

What is the correct way of achieving this?

### WHAT HAVE I TRIED SO FAR:

I have placed *ContentControl* in the second grid row, and am changing its *Content* on menu item click (below is the small code example).

*XAML:*

```
<Window x:Class="ZonaA.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:testUserControl="clr-namespace:ZonaA"
    Title="Zona A" 
    Height="350" Width="525" 
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu Grid.Row="0">
        <MenuItem Header="First user control" Click="C1" />
        <MenuItem Header="Second user control" Click=C2" />    
    </Menu>
    <ContentControl Name="windowContent" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
```

*Code behind:*

```
private void C1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        windowContent.Content = new myUserControl1();
    }

    private void C2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        windowContent.Content = new myUserControl2();
    }
```

Comment: Your approach is perfectly ok, if you choose to work code behind and simplest to understand and modify.

Comment: @NirajDoshi: Thank you. I just find it hard to believe there is no something like `Grid.Row[0] = something` which would make my task even easier...

Comment: Welcome to the world of Wpf from Winforms (I assume). It gives you much more flexibility when you can just edit the content. Because if you later plan to add/remove rows to grid you need to manually refactor RowIndexes of grid. And thats just one advantage. There are lot more depending on particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Frame`i think this woul do the Job too [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7QN2QoC20D8) is a Video where he uses a Frame to Switch the Content and the you just put no Content in the first page. hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach for your problem is use InteractionTriggers, here's an example.

First of all, if you decided go by this, you need the add the following references to your project:

**System.Windows.Interactivity**

**Microsoft.Expression.Interactions**

Doing do, its time to declare them in your XAML in order to use it:

```
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:ie="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

Now, if that being said, you can do all you want to do without write a single line on code-behind, which is great if you are following the MVVM pattern, here's like your MenuItem will be:

```
<MenuItem Header="First user control">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <ie:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="windowContent" PropertyName="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</MenuItem>
```

Basically you "assign"  the event of click, and performe some action when the event is fired, in our case, we'll execute a action called ChangePropertyAction, which will change the PropertyName="Visibility" to the control "windowContent" (the control name needs to be defined) to the value "Hidden".

You just have the adapt this example to your case, you have to declare both usersControls on XAML in order to change their properties.